# Same font for variable in \mathit and regular math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, mathpazo, fourier

I'm trying to have the same font for the p in `\mathit` (or `\textit`) (the idea is to have a multiletter variable) and the single p, with mathpazo and fourier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}

\[\mathit{ap}_i = p_i.\]

\end{document}
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) exactly what error do you get?

Comment: I get exactly the same glyph (in the Utopia Italic font). By the way, `fourier` will completely override the font settings done by `mathpazo`.

Comment: daleif, thank you. I get two different p's.
egreg, hmm… I wonder what is causing the two different p's then.

Comment: Show your log-file.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what was causing the problem:
I had a `\mathversion{…}` command that was changing the math font, and that I forgot about and couldn't see among all other commands.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Kindly,
NS